# Matrix Transformation Onto?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> A linear transformation $T\colon\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^2$ whose matrix is
>   $$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
> 1 & 3 & 3\\
> 2 & 6 & -3.5+k
> \end{array}\right)$$
>   is onto if and only if $k\neq$__________

I'm a little confused by the notation here, so is the matrix given here supposed to be the matrix $A$ such that $XA \Rightarrow Y$? And what does the $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ notation mean? Does that mean a $3\times 3$ matrix and a $2\times 2$ matrix respectively?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^n$ denotes [$n$-dimensional Euclidean space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_space).  The notation $T : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ means that $T$ send a $3$-dimensional vector to a $2$-dimensional vector.  A map $T : X \to Y$ is [onto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function) if every element $y \in  Y$ can be realized by a point $x \in X$ (I.e., for every element $y$ in $Y$, there is an element $x$ such that $T(x) = y$).  The question wants you to find the value(s) of $k$ such that the transformation $T : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is onto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$T$ takes in a column vector $(a_1, a_2, a_3)^T$, i.e. an element of $\mathbf R^3$, and sends it to
\[
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 3 & 3 \\
2 & 6 & -3.5 + k
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 \\
a_2 \\
a_3
\end{pmatrix}.
\]
Convince yourself that this results in a $2 \times 1$ matrix, i.e. an element of $\mathbf R^2$.

For the surjectivity: the [image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map#Kernel.2C_image_and_the_rank-nullity_theorem) of the transformation is the [span](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span) of the columns of the matrix (why?). You also know that $\mathbf R^2$ is spanned by any two non-zero vectors that are not parallel. What is the span of the first two columns of the given matrix?

Comment: Let me know if I should say more. I have to hop on a train for a bit, though.

Comment: How do I find the span of the first two columns?

Comment: @StickFigs The span $W$ of the first column is the space of scalar multiples of $(1, 2)$. So, vectors of the form $(x, 2x)$ for all $x \in \mathbf R$. Now, is the second column an element of $W$, or not?

Comment: Yes, it is. It's x=3 for (x,2x).

Comment: @StickFigs Exactly. So it's already contained in the span of the first column. For the "column space" to be all of $\mathbf R^2$, we need the third column to not be contained in $W$ (is it clear why?). What restriction does this give?

Comment: So it means that -3.5+k cannot equal 6, so k is 9.5?

Comment: @StickFigs I believe that's the answer, yes.